# While Binding SSL cert to the site - error "The system cannot find the file specified. ( Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)

Tags: ssl, iis

I am able to successfully complete Certificate request in IIS and it shows up under Server certificates. It also has a private key but I get this error "The system cannot find the file specified. ( Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) while binding it to the site. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please refresh IIS Manager to see if this certificate disappears, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does shows up in IIS on refresh and also shows up in the drop down on the edit bindings popup.